# Symbolic links without spaces for a given file set in bash

Tags: bash, symlink

I have the following code below, which is an attempt to create a symbolic link for each file matching the pattern *let.txt in the working folder, which has the same name as the original file but with underscores instead of spaces. I need to keep the original files untouched hence the use of symlinks.

The error I get is

ln: failed to access ‘*let.txt’: Too many levels of symbolic links

So I see the search string is getting passed very literally into tempstring, I don't know why. How do I correct my code?

```
for file in *let.txt; do

tempstring="${file// /_}"

ln -s "$file" $tempstring

done
```

Comment: If `ln` is seeing `*let.txt`, that means no files matched in the first place, and `file` is being set to the literal pattern rather than one result at a time. Use either `shopt -s failglob` or `shopt -s nullglob` before your loop to either raise an error early or do nothing silently, respectively.

Comment: Or, figure out why `*let.txt` isn't making an expected match in the first place.

Comment: What if some of your files don't have spaces in to start with? Note that having done it once you will now have an extra name that will match *let.txt. You might want to only perform the loop for `"* *let.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting quotes around all your variables when 1 variable is 1 parameter:

```
for file in *let.txt; do
tempstring="${file// /_}"
ln -s "$file" "$tempstring"
done
```

Tested and works on GNU bash, version 5.0.11(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0)